# Getting errors whenever I click on the choicebox

Tags: java, javafx, dropdownchoice

I created a `ChoiceBox` object called `backgroundChoiceBox`. I added the following code to my controller class:

```
@FXML
private ChoiceBox<String> backgroundChoiceBox = new ChoiceBox<>();
```

In the initialize method, I added these two lines of code:

```
backgroundChoiceBox.getItems().addAll("Trees", "Mountains");
backgroundChoiceBox.setValue("Trees");
```

When I run the program, the choice box appears with no errors being sent to the console. When I click on the choice box however, I receive the following errors.

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8100(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

My options for Trees and Mountains still show up and allow me to click them, but it results in the same sequence of errors appearing. If anyone could help explain why this is happening that would be great! Thanks in advance

Comment: do you have something in your FXML file about this ChoiceBox? If so, please share.

Comment: I doubt the following causes your error, but `= new ChoiceBox<>();` for an `@FXML` declared variable is [just wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26563347/having-an-issue-with-javafx-objects-losing-reference-once-theyre-put-into-an-ar).

Comment: The above code works fine for me (with JavaFX8)

Comment: @Moh-Aw yes i have this line:

    <ChoiceBox fx:id="backgroundChoiceBox" onMouseClicked="#choiceAction" prefWidth="150.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />

Comment: Also it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The initialization of you `ChoiceBox` should be handled by your FXML file.

For example:

```
<ChoiceBox fx:id="backgroundChoiceBox" value="Trees">
    <items>
        <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
            <String fx:value="Trees" />
            <String fx:value="Mountains" />
        </FXCollections>
    </items>
</ChoiceBox>
```

You are currently initializing your `ChoiceBox` twice. Once in the FXML file and once in the controller.

Remove `= new ChoiceBox<>();` from your controller class and remove the corresponding

```
backgroundChoiceBox.getItems().addAll("Trees", "Mountains");
backgroundChoiceBox.setValue("Trees");
```

from your initialization method. After that your `choiceAction` method should work without an exception.